# Baldurs Gate 3 - Trailer Dragons

Tags: baldurs-gate-3

I've watched the trailer a few times, and got a question there. The dragons shown in the trailer/intro are red dragons as it seems. Is there any clear indication as to what age class they are of? At first I would have guessed ancient ones, but due to how large they are compared to their riders they would seem quite smaller to me than I had thought ancient ones would be.

Thus what age class are they?

Comment: Historically, they've been Adult Red Dragons.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the size of the dragons comparative to the riders, and the fact that the riders are almost certainly gythyanki of medium size, it seems that the dragons can be at most huge in size and thus at most mature adults.  See https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/dragonTrue.htm

Comment: Note that BG3 is based on the D&D 5th edition rules, while that SRD is for D&D 3.5e. [Here are the basic rules for D&D 5e.](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules) (That said, the rest of your answer is still probably correct.)